# Importing several individual files into an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, import, ear

I have several files comprising a tomcat web application that I need to import into an eclipse project so that I can easily create an EAR file from them.

I have changed the names of some folders + files for privacy reasons.

My files are currently all in the folder `'test'`.

- `'test'` contains some HTML and JSP files (the forms for my
  application) as well as a JavaScript .js file and a CSS file.
- `'test'` also contains the folder `'WEB-INF'` which contains a TLD file,
  and my `web.xml` file.
- `'WEB-INF'` contains a `'lib'` folder, with `two .jar files`.
- `'WEB-INF'` also contains the `'classes'` folder, which merely contains
  the `'helpers'` folder.
- The `'helpers'` folder contains all the java source code- several
  servlets, and one helper class that does database communication
  stuff.

How would I import these into a new project in Eclipse?

I want everything to import, including my js, css, jsp and html, not just the java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joseph,

From eclipse you can import only 'war' files from the existing web application. If you have the war file you can directly do this, else you have to create a web project and manually add your files to the corresponding project folders.

Comment: I don't have a war file either, because that's what I wanted to make a project for, and from then it would be pretty easy to get the EAR

Comment: Then you can not import the web project to eclipse. Create the web project, then copy the files form your existing application to the eclipse project manually. Since you have the proper web-app folder structure maintained, I guess it will hardly takes more time.

Comment: Well, that was actually quite annoying (took about an hour since I'm a complete eclipse noob) yet I guess that's the only real solution. Still, it works, so I probably shouldn't complain.

Comment: May be one more try you can give is to create a war file manually using your web app contents. Use the jar command - jar cf ../mywebapp.war *  ,  later import this war file in your eclipse. I never tried this, however should work in best case.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have Eclipse Indigo and for testing I just created a new project. I right clicked on the project folder and selected import.
In the new window I selected General->FileSystem and then just browsed to the files I wanted (no matter the extension).
Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: This will import the file system, However this will not create a web project in eclipse.